Saving a vector layer with a different projection in the same directory as the original layer
I have a vector layer and I want to save it in the original directory, but I can't because access to the source file is denied.
projekcia_prj = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:3857")
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer("firstMap.shp", nazov, "ogr")
_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vlayer, "firstMap.shp", 'utf-8', projekcia_prj, 'ESRI Shapefile')

So I tried to another output file and overwrite the original one. It is also not possible to delete the original one because access is denied.
bb = QgsVectorFileWriter.deleteShapeFile(aa)

_writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(vlayer, "outMap.shp", 'utf-8', projekcia_prj, 'ESRI Shapefile')
bb = QgsVectorFileWriter.deleteShapeFile(vlayer.source())
shutil.copyfile("outMap.shp", "firstMap.shp")

I've been trying to google all day but can't find an answer why the file firstMap.shp and firstMap.dbf are still blocked for deletion or overwriting.
I tried too:
del(vlayer)

but it didn't help

I'm guessing you are using windows which won't let you do that. So you need to write to a new temporary file, then delete the first file and then move the temporary file to the first name.

Yes. I using Windows  .

If you install Windows PowerToys, you can use File Locksmith to see what process is locking the file, and also to unlock it. But this sounds like an OS issue more than a QGIS issue!

It's the read portion of the programme that holds the file lock.
